# Correct acknowledgment for a figure's digital rendering

Tags: authorship, copyright, graphics

If I draw a figure freehand, and then ask somebody else to render it digitally, and integrate the resulting product in a publication, what is the correct way of acknowledging this person's work?

Should I mention their name

1. As a co-author,
2. In the acknowledgments,
3. In the caption of the figure ("*Digital rendering by Doe, J.*")
4. Something else?

Comment: About 1. : why? If you go down that way, I guess you have to have as a co-author Mohammed ibn-Musa al-Khowarizmi, because he provided a good rendering of the idea of zero you have in mind :)

Answer (score 2):

Either 2 or 3 (or both) is proper. They haven't likely contributed to the intellectual content of the paper so 1 would not be required or advised. You did that when you drew the figure. Similarly reviewers and copy editors don't become authors.

If they put a lot of work into it, then both 2 and 3 would probably be best. And, for an acknowledgement, make sure you point to the figure if you don't also use a caption.